# @NotNull annotation doesn't throw exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-annotations

I have a problem. I want to throw an exception when an attribute is null, but the @NotNull annotation doesn't seem to be working. I use Spring 2.6.4

My controller:

```
@RestController
public class GroupController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/journey", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Group> create(@Valid @RequestBody GroupCreateCommand groupCreateCommand, BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {
        Group group = groupService.create(groupCreateCommand);
        journeyService.notifyNewGroup(group);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(group, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GroupCreateCommand {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("people")
    @NotNull
    private Integer people;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(Integer people) {
        this.people = people;
    }
}
```

Request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/journey' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"id": 3
}'
```

Result:
[image]

As you can see, the exception is not thrown, but the seats attribute is mapped as null.

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you in any way handling `ConstraintViolationException` or `MethodArgumentNotValidException`  anywhere or any parent exception? 
also can you remove BindingResult param and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are expecting validation result in BindingResult parameter.This parameter helps you in case you want some special handling for validation failures.
you can **remove BindingResult parameter from controller method** or you can add below code snippet in controller method to view validation error for request body

```
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        bindingResult.getFieldErrors().stream().forEach(error -> {
            System.out.println(error.getField() + ":" + error.getDefaultMessage());
        });
    }
```